# Remove password reset fields on user profile

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

Since we're only permitting logging in via the Drupal Admin and LDAP.

[image]

How might I turn off or hide these fields in the User's Edit Account (`user/xx/edit`) tab?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the password fields on the user edit form, put this code in your custom module, which implements [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7):

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  hide($form['account']['pass']);
}
```

You may also want to prevent users from going to `user/password` page and change their passwords on that page:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/password']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
  $items['user/password']['access arguments'] = array('administer users');
}
```

One more hint, if you want to remove the links on the user login block:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['links'] = '';
}
```